# MySQL does not allow me to login and shows SQL mode error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

When trying to login to mysql from command line in Ubuntu, I get the following error:

> mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'sql_mode=NULL'

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file looks like the following:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

I do not have a `~/.my.cnf`. I am not sure how to correct this error. I have tried both `sql_mode` and `sql-mode` in the cnf file. I have also tried both `[mysqld]` and `[mysql]` as header.

I would really appreciate if some SQL guru in SO can help me!

Comment: Did you take a look at your **mysqld.cnf** file in **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d**?

Comment: @nacho it does not have `sql_mode` entry in **mysqld.cnf**. I added and tried, but didnt work

Comment: Try setting the mode without the quotation marks